# Cannot find module 'url' Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, module

I jumped from console.log to source and from source to console.log few times and suddenly pop out this error( I wasn't in vsc)

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'url' utils.js:30

So i went there and i didn't see any problems.

```
var _url = require("url");
```

My git status doesn't appear change in module files. Really I don't know what I did, just enjoyed with debugber in browser.

var _url = **webpack_require**(Object(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module 'url'"); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }()));  <-this is source

and this is vsc terminal:
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/utils.js 31:35-50
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'M:\Praca\Programowanie\race cars UI\node_modules\css-loader\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error as well, seemly randomly.  It turned out that my editor (VSCode) had thought it would be a good idea to autocomplete the word `sort` and add this line to my imports:

```
import { sort } from "css-loader/dist/utils"
```